# How to add a char behind a line in a TXT file in Batch, (notice: the line is 10000 chars long, which has reached the batch variable limit)?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to add a character next to a line in a TXT file, without using the FOR /F command to copy the whole content/line in the TXT file, because the content inside the TXT file is 10000 characters long, and that would reach the variable limit. How do I have to code it?

I've tried to doing it with `echo.%var%>>output.txt`

This should be in the TXT file:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz etc. (10000 chars long)
```

Not this:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
etc.
```

Comment: What did `echo.%var%` do that wasn't what you wanted? Also, is this the only line in the text file, or are there a lot of very long lines?

Comment: Can you please explain exactly what is meant by "I want to add a character next to a line in a TXT file"? Every line, or a specific line, _(if specific, how to determine which?)_, and prefixed or suffixed? What character? What type of line endings and encoding does the `.txt` file have?

Answer (score 0):

Using a scripting language will introduce a great deal of overhead. The scripting executable, whether it is PowerShell, Python, Perl, or anything else, will need to be loaded each time it is invoked. Here is an example using PowerShell.

```
SET "VAR=a"
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "'%%s' | Out-File -FilePath 'output.txt' -Append -NoNewline"
SET "VAR=b"
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "'%%s' | Out-File -FilePath 'output.txt' -Append -NoNewline"
```

It is not clear how the VAR variable is created from your question. I would assume that it is some form of loop or a subroutine CALL.

```
SET "VAR=a b c d e f g h i j k l"
FOR %%s IN (%VAR%) DO (
    powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
        "'%%s' | Out-File -FilePath 'output.txt' -Append -NoNewline"
)
```

To eliminate the overhead required to load the scripting language many times, you might consider producing a temporary file containing multiple lines. Then, invoke the scripting language once to produce the final output file without newlines.

```
IF EXIST "appendtemp.txt" (DEL "appendtemp.txt")
SET "VAR=a b c d e f g h i j k l"
FOR %%c IN (%VAR%) DO (ECHO>>appendtemp.txt %%c)

powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
"Get-Content -Raw -Path 'appendtemp.txt' |" ^
    "ForEach-Object { $_ -replace \"`r`n\",'' } |" ^
    "Out-File -FilePath 'output.txt'"
```